# Vert.x passing a Future without execution

Tags: java, asynchronous, future, vert.x

I have a below piece of code:

```java
package starter;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;

public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start() {
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> req.response().end("Hello Vert.x!")).listen(8080);

    cacheFirst("key", Future.future(h -> {
      System.out.println("Call external API");
      h.complete("Call external API");
    }))
    .onComplete(h -> System.out.println("Success"))
    .onFailure(t -> System.out.println("Failed"));
  }

  private Future<String> cacheFirst(String key, Future<String> task) {
    Future<String> getCache = Future.future(h -> {
      h.complete("ABCXYZ");
    });

    return getCache.onSuccess(res -> {
      System.out.println("Data from cache: " + res);
    }).onFailure(t -> {
      task.onSuccess(res -> {
        System.out.println("Store task result to cache");
      }).onFailure(tt -> {
        System.out.println("Do nothing");
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Expected console output:

```
Data from cache: ABCXYZ
Success
```

Actual console output:

```
Call external API
Data from cache: ABCXYZ
Success
```

In function `start`, how can I pass a `Future` into `cacheFirst` function as an argument without having it executed?

In the real world scenario, the `cacheFirst` function will try to get data from cache store first and if it is found, there will be no need to execute the provided future (`Future<string> task`) to, for example, invoke a request to an external API.

Reproducer: https://github.com/triet-truong/vertx-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap it in inside a `Supplier` will produce expected result!

https://github.com/triet-truong/vertx-application/commit/6391c1b5d6b5f0e9b927ab0a9834b3ce6f0edf7f

```java
cacheFirst("key", () -> Future.future(h -> {
      System.out.println("Call external API");
      h.complete("Call external API");
    }))
    .onComplete(h -> System.out.println("Success"))
    .onFailure(t -> System.out.println("Failed"));
```

```java
private Future<String> cacheFirst(String key, Supplier<Future<String>> task) {
    Future<String> getCache = Future.future(h -> {
      h.complete("ABCXYZ");
    });

    return getCache.onSuccess(res -> {
      System.out.println("Data from cache: " + res);
    }).onFailure(t -> {
      task.get().onSuccess(res -> {
        System.out.println("Store task result to cache");
      }).onFailure(tt -> {
        System.out.println("Do nothing");
      });
    });
  }
```